# Entity Framework Fluent API: An object of type 'IndexAttribute' cannot be serialized by the IndexAnnotationSerializer.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, fluent

I'm using EF 6.1.3 and got this error.

**"An object of type 'IndexAttribute' cannot be serialized by the IndexAnnotationSerializer. Only 'IndexAnnotation' objects can be serialized."**

Here is one of the config files

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MasterDetails.Models;

namespace MasterDetails.DataLayer
{
    public class InventoryItemConfiguration :     EntityTypeConfiguration<InventoryItem>
{
    public InventoryItemConfiguration()
    {
        Property(ii => ii.InventoryItemCode)
            .HasMaxLength(15)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("AK_InventoryItem_InventoryItemCode") { IsUnique = true }));

        Property(ii => ii.InventoryItemName)
            .HasMaxLength(80)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAttribute("AK_InventoryItem_InventoryItemName") { IsUnique = true });

        Property(ii => ii.UnitPrice)
            .HasPrecision(18, 2);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is caused by the following line

```
.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAttribute("AK_InventoryItem_InventoryItemName") { IsUnique = true });
```

You need to wrap `IndexAttribute` inside the `IndexAnnotation` (as you already correctly did for the other column `InventoryItemCode`):

```
.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
    new IndexAttribute("AK_InventoryItem_InventoryItemName") { IsUnique = true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following code:

```
.HasMaxLength(50)
.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("AK_InventoryItem_InventoryItemName", 2) { IsUnique = false }));
```

And Remove `.IsRequired()`

IndexAttribute Has two overload, Second Overload is order.

Comment: .IsRequired is okay. : ) You can use it.